# Why is $df_x(h)$ linear in $h$?

Tags: real-analysis

Im trying to read Milnor's "topology from a differentiable viewpoint" and I can't seem to understand the following statement on page 3, " For any smooth map $f:U\rightarrow V$ the derivative $df_x:R^k\rightarrow R^\ell$ is defined by the formula $df_x(h)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}(f(x+th)-f(x))$ for $x\in U$ , $h\in R^k$. Clearly $df_x(h)$ is a linear function in $h$" How does this follow from the definition? Why would it necessarily be true that $$\lim \frac{f(x+t(h_1+h_2))-f(x)}{t}=\lim \left( \frac{f(x+th_1)-f(x)}{t}\right) +\lim \left(\frac{f(x+th_2)-f(x)}{t}\right)?$$

Also, how is this definition the same as the definition of total derivative from multivariable calculus? The total derivative that I'm used to is the function

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{dt}+\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial f}{\partial u_i} \frac{du_i}{dt}$$

and I don't see how this is the same thing as the definition given by Milnor. The ordinary definition that I'm familiar with (above) is a function of the variable $x$, but the definition given by Milnor seems to be a function of some other variable $h$, and it seems that he's saying it is the derivative "at x" but somehow depending on $h$, in the sense of a directional derivative. Obviously I'm confused, so please forgive me if any of what I'm saying isn't making sense. I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: I think Milnor's book assumes you have already taken a course in multivariate calculus. Hence, he expects you to recognise in that definition of $df_x$ the total derivative of the $C^\infty$ function $f:\Bbb R^k\to\Bbb R^\ell$.

Comment: (total derivative in the point $x$)

Comment: The last equation in your question is not what Milnor is claiming, even after you fix the typo ($h_1$ in the last fraction should be $h_2$). He's claiming that the two sides have the same limit as $t\to0$, not that they are equal for arbitrary $t$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Can you help me to understand how this definition is the same as that given in multivariable calculus? It looks to me more like a directional derivative. Does $h$ not represent a "direction"?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, I understand that. Could you help me to see why the limits are the same?